# What's the best flow for AWS guest only app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to build a simple card game where one sets his nickname and is able to play with other players.

I have a few API Gateway HTTP endpoints and while I want only guests too access this app, I only want guest coming from my application to be able to access it.

I'm not sure if it's possible (pretty new at aws & general security.
Currently I have only guest identity pools but I'm not sure how to attach an guest authoriser to the api gateway.

My question is what is the best flow for this, how should I go about it, should I just create user pools? (I'd prefer not to)

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible using unauthenticated id pool. You won't get any tokens but you can send the temporary aws credentials and have a custom authorizer verify these credentials before forwarding the call to your API handler lambda.

Comment: Yes, I've been researching and the best way I could figure out was a custom lambda authorizer